# docker volume mapped with filesystem (windows)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this lighted docker-compose file :

```
version: "2"
services:
  orthanc:
    build: orthanc
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: ["${PORT}:8042"]
    volumes: ["orthanc-storage:/var/lib/orthanc/db:Z"]
    [...]
volumes:
  orthanc-storage:
```

I don't understand how I finally define the volume `orthanc-storage` to link `C:/tmp` for example.

Someone could explain it to me ? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By default the driver used is local to assign volumes and creates the volume on host at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<project_name>_dbdata` in Linux. Not confirm where does it points in windows.

You can define the volumes to use different driver and give the path to the volume like this

```
version: "2"
services:
  orthanc:
    build: orthanc
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: ["${PORT}:8042"]
    volumes: ["orthanc-storage:/var/lib/orthanc/db:Z"]
    [...]
volumes:
  orthanc-storage:
volumes:
  orthanc-storage:
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: "C:/tmp"
```